# How Does Pipeline Know Which Branch To Get The azure-pipeline.yml From?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

In my `main` branch, I have the `trigger` property in the `azure-pipeline.yml` looking at the `main` branch only

```
trigger:
- main
```

I then created another branch called `test-pipeline` and in that branch, I updated the `trigger` to include everything:

```
trigger:
- '*'
```

Then I built the `test-pipeline` branch using Azure Pipeline.

Now every time I push a commit to the `test-pipeline` branch, the Azure Pipeline build is triggered. How does that work? I thought Azure Pipeline only looks at the `main` branch for config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does that work? I thought Azure Pipeline only looks at the main
> branch for config?

No, Azure Pipelines reads the build defintion from the commits you push, not from any specific branch.

When you create a new pipeline you select a repository and specify the name of a file which includes your build definition (usually `azure-pipeline.yml`)

Once the pipeline is setup Azure Pipelines will **evaluate every commit** that is pushed to the repository. It will look into the triggers specified in `azure-pipeline.yml` for that particular commit and decide whether or not to start the pipeline.

What is happening in your case is that you are pushing a commit where the trigger is set to `'*'`, which means regardless of what branch it will trigger a build

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have a follow up question. Does that mean developers need to fork the repo and create PR to the upstream to avoid changing the build definition accidentally? I work in a small team and we don't currently fork the repo. I can see developers could create their own branch and then could accidentally update the build definition and push it to a remote branch and that would trigger unwanted builds.

Comment: Yes, that would reduce that risk. However at some time you may want to make a PR of that fork, pulling in the changes. If you do a build as part of the PR it will be based on the build definition in the PR.

If you really want to detach the build definition from your code you should look into [Classic build pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#define-pipelines-using-the-classic-interface). That way you can keep the build definition external to the repo with its own set of access rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.